# How to increase stack limit permanently without restarting

Tags: linux, ulimit, stack

I need to increase the default stack size on Linux. As I know there are usually two ways:

- `ulimit -s size`
- `/etc/security/limits.conf`

The ulimit method only works as long as I am logged in.

limits.conf will work after a restart.

Is there a possible way to increase the limit without restarting?

Comment: There must be a way to do this.  The ulimit shell command doesn't work for a user. And the current logged in user doesn't have permission to alter their limit unless they are root.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with editing your `.bashrc` file to do a `ulimit -s size` every time you start a terminal session?

Comment: unfortunately that is not for me as a user, it is for the couchdb process, which crashes because a document in the DB is to big to fit in the stack.

Comment: @Simon: that means you're currently restarting that process every time? How is that done? Can't you splice the `ulimit -s size` in the scripts that control the restarts?

Comment: well, it is a subprocess of couchdb that crashes (couchjs). So all processes started by the user couchdb should have a bigger stack

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this programatically, you can use the [`setrlimit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) function.

Comment: unfortunately I need to set the limit for couchdb, not for a program of my own. So setting it programatically is out of question

Answer (score 1):

Linux (and POSIX compatible systems in general) *inherit* current process limits from existing processes when a new process is started (using `fork()` or `exec()`). As a result, you would just need to change the limits for *all existing processes* that are already running on your system. The config files just define the values for the initial processes after the system has been booted and everything else inherits the current values of parent processes.

Why would you want to increase stack limit of everything? Do *all* your existing processes immediately require increased stack space for some reason?

If you actually need to change the limits of any given process after that process has already been started, you can do it with command `prlimit` which uses kernel interface `int prlimit(pid_t pid, int resource, const struct rlimit *new_limit, struct rlimit *old_limit)` behind the scenes. It requires `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` for many use cases so you often need to run that as `root` in practice.

Answer (score 0):

limits.conf don't need a restart.

It just needs a new session to work.

You need to logout and login.